# Notepad ++ add new paragraph after specific symbol

Tags: text, replace, notepad++, pdftotext

I have a text that it is in one row. My purpose is to bring every new statement to a new row. After every "." symbol I want next statement to be on new row. How to achieve that. I have already tried to replace `.\s*` with `.\n` but that delete rest of text and just replace it with a "."

Comment: Maybe all you need is an *Extended* replace mode with `.` --> `.\n` replacement? This won't remove the leading spaces though. If that is important, you can use a regex based replacement `\.\s*` --> `.\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Notepad++'s **Regular Expression** search feature with ". matches newline" checked, Now type `\..` in **Find what** and `.\nText Text Text\n` in **Relace with** and hit Replace all.

## Updated

For every character including "-".

**Find what:** `\.([^.]+)`,

**Replace with:** `.\n$1`

Comment: Can I do same but before any symbol. Let say new line before "-"

Comment: for further regular expression study you can visit http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: You do not need to enable *`.` matches newline* because there is no `.` in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use replace tool in *Extended* mode (not the regexp) and put "." to replace with "\n". Or escape the point which is a special character in regexp mode:

[image]